# git clone: How do I clone an Android 2.2 compatible branch of Browser?

Tags: android, git

I managed to clone the latest & greatest version of Android's Browser source code, using:

```
  git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/Browser.git
```

The problem now is that, with my system (and emulator) setup for 2.2, Eclipse complains about errors in the cloned package. I suspect those errors come from incompatibility between the latest Browser code and the older Android 2.2.

How do I find the list of available Git branches for Android?

What else do I need to do to fetch the exact Browser version that is compatible with Android 2.2?

Comment: Maybe http://android.git.kernel.org/ could be something you're interested in. If not then I'm not sure if I understand that part of the question properly.

Comment: @Victor I already got the URL. I even got the latest version. But the Git repository contains multiple versions/branches of the project. I would like to fetch/clone an **older** one. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I find the list of available Git branches for Android?

```
git remote show origin
```

> What else do I need to do to fetch the exact Browser version that is compatible with Android 2.2?

Since you cloned it, you’ve already fetched all of the branches. But you can use this command to fetch just the branch you need:

```
git fetch origin froyo:froyo
```

And once you have fetched it, use this command to check it out:

```
git checkout froyo
```

Next time, you can get the branch you want in one step with

```
git clone -b froyo git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/Browser.git
```

This will fetch every branch as well, but that’s not a big deal.